# Android studio, unlocks the activity everyday after a given time

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, scheduled-tasks

I have this quiz, when user take the quiz I get the created_at time and I want it to be available after the same time tomorrow until then it should be locked. How do I schedule the task? Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) to save date/time of last quiz and check this value when starting app again, then lock or unlock GUI

Comment: @snachmsm This won't work as a user can change device time and access it.

Comment: @snachmsm Can you save date in sharedpreferences?

Comment: @Praven - without syncing with 3rd party there is a lot of possibilities to "hack" app. @op - you can store it as a timestamp (so `long`)

Answer (score 1):

You can manage it using server time. So you use a scheduler and check the server time and set your logic.